# Is there a simple way of knowing running Heroku processes from within a process?

Tags: heroku, process, cedar

I'd quite like to know whether there's a simple way of knowing the list of running processes in your app, from *inside* a running process.

For instance, let's say I have a `web` process and a `worker` process. From within the `web` process, can I know that I have 2 `worker` processes running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can that by adding heroku Gem in your Gemfile.

and then running system commands from code. I have tried this on heroku bash

Running bash attached to terminal... up, run.1
~ $ heroku
~ $ 
~ $ heroku -v
2.25.0
~ $ heroku ps

Process                  State       Command

---

web ....

It will prompt for password so you can your heroku client class for login purpose and then listing all processes.

Hope this will help you.